# How to prevent \texttt from making the text bold

Tags: typewriter

I tried to escape the underscore character but the resultant "_" did not look perfect. Then I came across another answer suggesting to use \texttt. However, I see that \texttt is also boldening the text. Is there a way to circumvent this problem? Here is a minimal example to explain what I mean.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
\texttt{This\_is\_a\_}test
%There is a clear difference between the fonts of the contents inside \texttt and outside.
\end{document}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You say *the resultant "_" did not look perfect*. What output are you trying to achieve?

Comment: \texttt switches to a different (typewriter) font.

Answer (score 1):

That’s how the default serif and monospace fonts look.  You can change either of them.

For example, New Computer Modern Roman comes in a slightly-heavier Book weight.  This MWE pairs the Book weight of New Computer Modern Roman with the Regular weight of New Computer Modern Mono.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\setmainfont{NewComputerModernBook}
\setmonofont{NewComputerModernMono}

\begin{document}
\texttt{This\_is\_a\_}test
%There is a clear difference between the fonts of the contents inside \texttt and outside.
\end{document}
```

[image: New Computer Modern sample]

Maybe those specific fonts are not enough of a correction for your liking, but many font families come in multiple weights that you could try.